# Google Scholar Import - Jabref

Tags: bibtex, jabref, doi

I am a huge fan of Jabref - and Google Scholar. 
Using the Scholar search in Jabref  gives however unsatisfactory results.

I am not getting the URL/DOI information - nor the PDF automatically imported.

Is there a way to get this done ?

THX
J

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Can you screenshots of the search and results.

Comment: I think you may of bumped up against a bug: https://sourceforge.net/p/jabref/bugs/1266/

Comment: The bug you are describing is rather old i think. i might remark that the search always gives what i am looking for. its just that it doesn't then add URL/DOI info to th ebibtex entry after import - or give the PDF ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, importing the URL/DOI information or the PDF does not work automatically with the Google Scholar importer.

There is [a feature request in the issue tracker of JabRef](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/431) that asks for this, including the import of the abstract. Maybe you could comment there to show the developers that this is important, which might drive someone to implement it - Or maybe you could think about contributing yourself?

Regarding the automatic PDF import, you can get this done with a sort of workaround after importing the entry (Assuming you use at least JabRef 3.0):

1. Select the entry in the entry table
2. Go to the `General` tab
3. Hit the `Auto` button in the end of the `File` row.

This kicks of an online search on Google Scholar for the PDF and downloads the PDF if it is found and can be downloaded.

Comment: I am actually using v3.2 - i was just puzzled because they said a while ago it works... Thank you for your tips i am doing exactly that - but i hoped for more a one button does all approach as Google Scholar is quite useful to me already ...

Comment: Google Scholar changes its data format quite frequently, so it might be the case that it used to work, but stopped after updates by google. We'll see, maybe we get this fully functional again.